# How to set default branch policies in azure devops

Tags: git, azure-devops, azure-devops-rest-api

Is it possible to set branch policies across all repo's? In other words, When creating a branch, a default branch policy is already set for master.

Comment: Just searching for this myself, cannot believe this is not possible....

Answer (score 10, accepted):

It's been changed now. So for others who look for it, you can find it there:

1. **Project Settings*
2. 'Repositories'
3. All repositories -> 'Policies' tab
4. On the bottom there should be 'Branch policies' section with '+' button

[Screen from the mentioned view](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fLx7S.png)

Comment: How is this voted as the correct answer?  It doesn't address the question at all.

Comment: How is this not addressing the question? He explains the current implementation for setting branch policies across all repositories.  That's what the original question was asking.

Comment: @codeedward do you know if there is a way to make some repositories in a project to ignore the all repo policies?

The reason being we have 2 teams in one project, but each team works on different repositories and works in a different way

Answer (score 7):

Indeed as @Thomas Harris mentioned in the comment above, you can set it for all repos in a single project via

1. **Project Settings*
2. **Cross-repo policies** under "Repos" heading
3. Click **Add branch protection** button

And then you can select whether this applies to the default branch or a specific branch name pattern.

[image: Set project-wide branch protection via Project Settiongs]

Answer (score 6):

Right now you can't. You could listen to events in Azure DevOps for project creation for example and then set the policy yourself. For some information how to start see here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/repos/git/create-pr-status-server-with-azure-functions?view=vsts

Comment: @jessehouwing has documented a way to achieve this through the API: https://jessehouwing.net/azure-repos-git-configuring-standard-policies-on-repositories/

Comment: It is now possible to set global branch policies in the settings area for the project. Although I cannot find good documentation for this process.

Comment: Hi Thomas, you can find it under "cross-repo policies" and yes, it is poorly documented. Thanks for pointing that out. I will pass that along as feedback